# First order logic for proving a prime number

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The first order logic representation from a solution that I saw for showing that a positive $x$ is prime is

$$
\forall x  \ \operatorname{prime}(x) \iff \forall y,z  \ \ x = y*z \implies y = 1 \ \lor z = 1
$$

I don't think this is entirely correct because it doesn't account for `x=1`. A $z \neq y$ is needed.

My other question is could ($\forall y,z  \ \ x = y*z \implies y = 1 \ \lor z = 1$) be written as
$$
\forall y,z  \ \ x = y*z \land (y = 1 \ \lor z = 1)
$$
This seems to also work, but I'm not very experienced with logic representation.

Comment: Your proposed identity does not hold. A implies B is not in general equivalent to A and B, it is equivalent to not A or B. The prime formula does include the possibility of y=z=1 which would make 1 a prime number, which it is not defined to be (i.e. prime is >1 and y and z need to be different, with y and z both smaller than x, by definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I presume that all numbers here are natural numbers, i.e. it's assumed that all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$.

(1) You're right: this condition does make $x=1$ "prime", which it isn't. Something is missing here and needs to be corrected. We can't just require, though, that $x\ne y$, because it could be that $y=x$ and $z=1$. We need to be a little more careful and require that either $y$ or $z$ isn't equal to $x$. Another solution could be to specifically exclude $x=1$ by literally saying that $x\ne1$. So we can do things like:
$$\forall x \; \operatorname{prime}(x) \iff (x\ne1) \land (\forall y,z : [x=y\cdot z \implies y=1 \lor z=1])$$
or
$$\forall x  \; \operatorname{prime}(x) \iff \forall y,z : [x = y\cdot z \implies (y=1 \lor z=1) \land (y\ne x \lor z\ne x)]$$
(although the latter can be simplified, I guess).

(2) Your proposed definition doesn't work. You're saying that **for any** two integers $y$ and $z$, the previously chosen number $x$ is their product, $x=y\cdot z$, which can't be true. For example, imagine $x=10$. That definition says that $10=y\cdot z$ **for any** two integers $y$ and $z$…

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It should have been $y \neq z$ instead of $x \neq y$ -- I think this would work? Still trying to wrap my head around the second point.

Comment: Ah I got the second point now.

Comment: @Iamanon: Yes, $y\neq z$ would work even better!

Comment: Regarding (2), is my statement also saying that for any two integers, y or z must be 1?

Comment: @Iamanon: Yes, that's what that statement actually says. And that's not true either, because we can easily find two positive integers $y$ and $z$ neither of which is $1$ -- for example, $y=2$ and $z=3$.